# Вопрос по модулю SQlite 3 для python: почему выводит пустой список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

При попытки вывести данные из базы данных, он выводит пустой список. Почему может это быть?

```
request_database = ('SELECT User_ID FROM ' + 'id' + str(self.p_id) + ';' )
cursor.execute(request_database)
database_id = cursor.fetchall()
return database_id
```

1)да я знаю так делать нельзя но увы я слишком туп для более лучшего кода
2)Я делал по примеру

[image: как-то так]

Comment: `Я делал по примеру` хорошо в таких случаях добавлять ссылку на пример, а то это или неправильный пример или вы допустили ошибку, когда пример переписывали

Comment: cursor.execute('SELECT User_ID FROM test_table'

Comment: @Егор, так у вас нет таблицы test_table, только таблицы с именами idNNNN и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в `SQL`-запросе:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT User_ID FROM test table')
```

И при выполнении того кода будет исключение:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "table": syntax error
```

Попробуйте так `SQL`: `'SELECT User_ID FROM test'`

Comment: извиняюсь за ошибку, но он всё равно выводит пустой список. Мог бы кинул сейчас скриншот, но нельзя

Comment: @Егор, если в таблице ничего нет, то будет пустой список

Comment: вот имено там всё есть *добавил скриншот бд и изменил на истиный код

Comment: понял... спасибо